# qtfm: error while loading shared libraries:

Tags: libraries

Install qtfm, on 12.04 but it would not open.

Opening in a terminal yields this message:

qtfm: error while loading shared libraries: libmagic.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

How do I fix?

Comment: How did you install qtfm exactly? Are you on 32-bit or 64-bit Ubuntu?

Comment: I used the deb from:  http://www.qtfm.org/qtfm_5.5-1_i386.deb which appears to be 32-bit.  I run 64-bit.  Is that my problem? I did not see it in the regular repositories.  It's not a big deal if I can't run it.  I just saw it in a post and wanted to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a 32-bit program on a 64-bit install, and missing the 32-bit libraries needed to run the program. The failure is due to the program needing the 32-bit version, and the 64-bit version being loaded instead.

You can run `sudo apt-get install libmagic1:i386` (in 12.10 or newer) to install the 32-bit version, which should hopefully resolve the issue. On 12.04, you will have to be running the 32-bit version to use the 32-bit version of `qtfm`. On 64-bit you will have to use a 64-bit build of the application, either pre-built, or installing from source.

Comment: msg: The following packages will be REMOVED:
  brasero brasero-cdrkit casper codeblocks cracklib-runtime
  debhelper dvd+rw-tools dvdstyler ebook-speaker file
  file-roller genisoimage glade-gnome gnome-common intltool k3b
  kdenlive libbrasero-media3-1 libcodeblocks0 libmagic1
  libmlt++3 libmlt4 libpam-cracklib libsox-fmt-alsa
  libsox-fmt-base libsox-fmt-mp3 libsox1b libtool lives
  lupin-casper melt mkvtoolnix openshot python-mlt3
  rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder sleuthkit sox ubuntu-standard
  ubuntustudio-video usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk
  usb-creator-kde videoporama xubuntu-desktop

Comment: I don't want to break these other packages. I think I will stick to Thunar and Nautilus.  Thanks anyway.